# Ruby 2.1.3 options hash cannot be assigned with fetch

Tags: ruby, hash, fetch

Please explain to me why this is happening:

```
def resizeImage(event_file, resize_width, resize_height, options = {})
  puts options
  aspect_ratio = options.fetch(:maintain_aspect_ratio, true)
  puts aspect_ratio
  "return value"
end


resizeImage('event_file', 'resize_width', 'resize_height', {maintain_aspect_ratio: false} )
{:maintain_aspect_ratio=>false}
false
 => "return value"
```

I want to set a variable to = the fetch from the hash to make my code more readable. But for some reason it is nil when I call it. It almost looks like the fetch is asynchronous, but this ain't ajax.

This is a pretty elementary problem I know, but so far as I can tell I am doing things just as they are described in more than one guide to using options in ruby methods.

-- Update --

so now I have it returning something else to try to separate the problem. I see that the puts statement for aspect_ratio doesn't actually return anything at all. What is happening?

-- Update2 --

Okay, I got confused. It is returning false. So there is something else wrong in my real method. Thank you for your time, I will accept the most detailed answer but I appreciate both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have the correct structure down, however the final puts in your method is causing the return value to be nil. Ruby utilizes an implicit return, so unless specified, it will return the last value of a method. remove the `puts aspect_ratio` from the method, or ensure the last line is `aspect_ratio` and the method will properly return your value

```
def resizeImage(event_file, resize_width, resize_height, options = {}) 
  puts options
  aspect_ratio = options.fetch(:maintain_aspect_ratio, true)
  puts aspect_ratio #remove this line
  aspect_ratio
end
```

this can end up being shortened to

```
def resizeImage(event_file, resize_width, resize_height, options = {}) 
  options.fetch(:maintain_aspect_ratio, true)
end
```

Comment: I see. Thank you and the person above for your answers, you're right. But does that mean I can't use aspect_ratio within the method (obviously I was trying to simplify the problem).   How can I access aspect ratio within the method? I will modify my question above to illustrate.

Comment: you can add as many puts statements as you'd like into the method (or continue to use aspect ratio throughout). the important takeaway, is that you ensure the last line in your method returns the value you want your method to return. since you wanted to return aspect_ratio, your last line cannot be put(aspect_ratio), since puts returns nil.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I made a false assumption. I was updating an existing working method to use options instead of a mandatory aspect ratio field. When it stopped working after I defined the variable by options instead, I assumed the problem was because of options. But actually it is probably just my module assets in rails being janky and not updating consistently.

Comment: Actually the real problem was that I forgot I had a different branch in another version of the repo open in the terminal, and was starting rails from the wrong repo. Shoestring workflow~ That's one good reason changes you're making don't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line from your method:

```
puts aspect_ratio
```

Your Ruby method is returning to the value of the final statement, i.e. the value of `puts`.

When you remove that line, then your method will return `aspect_ratio`.

Comment: `p aspect_ratio` would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

@joelparkerhendersons answer is correct

Im going to explain whats happening.

Everything in ruby returns something(apart from a tiny minority). It can be forced by using `return` but by default the last line of the method is returned.

Your method `resizeImage` returns what `puts` returns. `puts` returns `nil`

Therefore as @joelparkerhendersons suggested remove the `puts`